# Windows 10 just logs me out when I select hibernate or sleep (complete shutdown works fine)

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I have a problem with my Windows 10. New hardware, fresh Windows 10 installation but when I try to put my computer to sleep or hibernate, the screen just goes black for a while and when I move the mouse or press a keyboard button it comes back showing the login screen. I tried leaving it alone for 5 minutes but that didn't change anything.

I already tried the following:

- Install latest Windows 10 updates (Build 1903)
- Install latest drivers and BIOS firmware
- Disable fast startup
- Disable wakeup for all devices with powercfg (keyboard, mouse, LAN controller)
- Disable and re-enable hibernate option in boot menu
- Run the Windows power troubleshooting tool
- Go to hibernate / sleep via power button and start menu option

Behavior is always the same. Complete shutdown works fine but hibernate / sleep just gets me to the login screen after a few seconds of black screen.

The event log shows only this message afterwards:

"User-mode process attempted to change the system state by calling SetSuspendState or SetSystemPowerState APIs." (Information / Source: Kernel-Power)

This is my hardware setup:

- Ryzen 3700X
- MSI X470 Gaming Plus Max (UEFI Boot Mode)
- 32GB 3200Mhz CL16 Kingston Hyper-X Predator
- Toshiba TR150 960GB SSD
- Be Quiert Straight Power 550W
- Gainward Phoenix GS GTX1070
- Asus Xonar Essence STX
- AC600 Wifi USB Stick (RTL8811AU)

Anyone got any more ideas?

Comment: Check in the BIOS setup for options relating to S1, S3, sleep, and similar and make sure they are enabled.

Comment: Looked through every everything, there is no option sounding even remotely like that.

Comment: Someone [here](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=309115.0) seemed to have a similar problem, which they blamed on RAID1 drives. I suspect that what fixed their issue was actually clearing the CMOS and resetting the BIOS settings to default... have you update the BIOS to the latest from manufacturer?

Comment: Yes and also did a CMOS reset afterwards, since MSI's Windows BIOS update tool is a little buggy.

Comment: Btw., I don't know if it's relevant but at first my PC also had trouble shutting down. It would just reboot instead. After I turned off fast startup the issue was gone. But I think it's a similar problem with hibernate. When I try it the first time it does write a lot to disk and only afterwards it goes back to the login screen. When I try it the second time in a row it however, it only takes a few seconds to get there and there is not much write activity.

Comment: Update: Hibernate is still not working but sleep is for some reason. Don't know exactly what it was but one thing I did was enabling ErP in BIOS. Unfortunately I need to remove power from my pc completely over night, so I still need hibernate as well. Would be really glad if someone had another clue for me.

Comment: I am only adding that I have the exact same problem and have tried the same things. If I find anything out I'll report back here. Sleep does seem to work for me - power light will flash as it goes into low power - it's just hibernate where it'll simply blank out at the login screen without changing power state. Shutdown is also similarly affected until you disable fast start, since with fast start it's kind of a mini-hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after I had migrated my OS from a hard drive to a SSD. During the migration I also changed the boot mechanism from MBR/classic to GPT/UEFI. To achieve that I created a new FAT32 partition (so called EFI/ESP partition) and copied the required files from another system running GPT/UEFI. Then had I created a new BCD store with the required entires. All these steps had been performed while I was running Win10 PE from a special USB stick (c't emergency windows usb stick https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/c-t-Notfall-Windows-2020-4514169.html).

After the migration the system was booting normally, but suffered from the same problems described by the OP.

Because I was using a SSD now, I also wanted to change the SATA access mode from RAID to AHCI. I tried this guide: [Switch RAID to AHCI without reinstalling Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10).

When trying any bcdedit operations I got an error message, that the BCD store could not be accessed. This seemed weird to me, I knew that I had created the BCD store after the migration and without the BCD store the system would not be able to boot.

Google'ing what could be the reason for an inaccessible BCD did not give me any useful result.

Then I started comparing the boot environment of the system I had copied the EFI boot files and my migrated system. After some more research I discovered that the EFI partition must be of a certain partition type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition

During the migration I had created a "simple FAT32" partition. It's a bit strange that the  system did boot with this setup. But Windows could not access (find) the BCD store, because the partition did not have the required identifier. This also seems to affect the configuration of power states (hibernation, sleep).

I deleted the "simple FAT32" partition, created an "ESP/UEFI" partition instead. Created a new BCD store and after that, my hibernation / "hybrid shutdown" problems were gone.

To cut a long story short: if Windows has a problem with the BCD store, your will get problems with hibernation/sleep/hybrid shutdown.

So it might be worth checking this. Simply open a command prompt with admin rights an type:
bcdedit

It should list at least two entries named:
"Windows Boot Manager" and "Windows Boot Loader".

Comment: Wow this totally fixed my system that was acting strange after an SSD migration too. I removed my bogus System partition and created a new one following DISKPART instructions from a search. Success!!

Answer (score 0):

After posting my comment in which I had tried everything you'd tried, I trawled the BIOS settings for anything to opportunistically change. In the end I disabled virtualisation (Hyper-V), rebooted, and picked Hibernate from the Start menu. To my surprise after a few seconds of thought my computer shut down, and on turning it back on it restores from hibernation. In Event Viewer, after the "attempted to change the system state" message it is followed by "The system is entering sleep." with a target state of S5, so it got further than before.

You may not have virtualisation enabled so this may be setting you up for disappointment but I'd been fairly convinced it was BIOS related so it's worth twiddling with a few things (as long as you're confident you aren't going to break your system).

Update: I found [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1261519/laptop-wont-hibernate-if-hyper-v-enabled-on-windows-10-pro) that confirms that Hyper-V disables hibernate and sleep. How annoying, particularly in how it behaves like this rather than tell you why it won't work!

Comment: Thanks for the input but there is no Hyper-V service in Windows 10. At least not in my installation. Also, virtualization is disabled by default in my BIOS. Seems like this solution is not applicable in my case. :(

Comment: It's in Windows 10 Pro only, I think. Did think it would be a bit of a long shot for you but maybe someone out there will find this and find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this thread as it took a while to find a fix for this.

I was able to resolve this issue by using the following steps to re-create the `bcdboot` file, please note this will only work on GPT drives, not MBR.

Run CMD as ADMIN

```
cmd> diskpart​
DISKPART> list disk 
DISKPART> select disk 0​ # ( or 1, depending on where the OS is installed.)
DISKPART> list partition​
```

You cannot delete the old ESP section while on Windows. You need to have some space to create a new ESP partition. If you do not have free space available, you may try shrinking one of the partitions.

```
DISKPART> select partition x​ # (go for the largest partition)
DISKPART> shrink desired=500​
DISKPART> create partition efi​
DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick​
DISKPART> assign letter=H​
DISKPART> exit​
```

Finally, you install the bootloader in the newly created partition with `bcdboot`.

```
cmd> bcdboot C:\windows /s H:
```

If everything went fine so far, restart your PC and Sleep/Hibernate should start working again!

Comment: I mistakenly deleted the ESP partition while on Linux with a backup partition image. I recreated a partition and restored from the image. Although I was able to boot Windows, hybrid shutdown was not working dropping to the login screen. I tried `fdisk` and created an EFI partition and restored from the partition image again. That did *not* work either. Finally, I saw this solution. I already had some small free space in the disk so skipped the shrink part. It worked perfectly. One should pick the new partition in BIOS on boot and later delete the old boot partition, as well. Thank you!