# Hybrid Sleep not available with WSL2?

Tags: windows-10, wsl2, hybrid-sleep

System:

- Windows 10 x64 Pro
- Ryzen 5900X on X570 Motherboard

I am using Docker for Windows and WSL2 on my system. I noticed that in the power options I am unable to enable *Hybrid Sleep*, even though *Standby (S3)* and *Hibernate* alone are available. `powercfg` states the following reason for *Hybrid Sleep* not being available: **The hypervisor does not support this standby state**

```
powercfg.exe -a
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Hybrid Sleep
        The hypervisor does not support this standby state.
```

Now searching for this particular problem seems a bit difficult, as mostly results show up that relate to either Standby or Hibernate not being available for different reasons. Which is not the case here.

I did however find some information that *Hybrid Sleep* is not available when *Hyper-V* is enabled, e.g. https://superuser.com/a/1261616/122639 . But the *Hyper-V* component is definitely not enabled on my system (I checked in "Turn Windows features on or off").

There are some indications that this is also the case if you use WSL2 (see [How to activate sleep states after Windows 10 install](https://superuser.com/questions/1179987/how-to-activate-sleep-states-after-windows-10-install) for instance). I just cannot find a definite answer. So - is it by design that *Hybrid Sleep* is not available when WSL2 is in use?

Comment: WSL2 requires a subset of Hyper-V called VirtualMachinePlatform.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey can you please post this as a regular answer, so that I can mark it accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

WSL2 didn't make a difference, and I didn't have Hyper-V enabled, but after much looking around and experimentation I did notice that in the enabled Windows features list I did have "Virtual Machine Platform" checked. Turned that off and now Hybrid Sleep is available!

I don't know if that's necessary for running, e.g. VMWare/VirtualBox, or what it's used for, but this is at least one possible solution.

Comment: By disabling that, you'll find that WSL2 will no longer function.  As @MichaelHarvey mentioned in the comments, VMP is essentially the parts of Hyper-V that are needed for WSL2.

Comment: Correct, WSL no longer works for me, so it's a choice. For me on this computer Hybrid Sleep is more important.

Comment: Well okay, but that means that you are essentially just restating the premise of the *question*, which says that Hybrid Sleep isn't available when WSL2 is enabled ;-)

Comment: You're nitpicking, the question in the text was "I just cannot find a definite answer. So - is it by design that Hybrid Sleep is not available when WSL2 is in use?", a comment below indicated VirtualMachinePlatform, but didn't say how to fix that. I spelled it out as a verified solution - OK?

Comment: I do regret that we disagree on this, but the question said, "Hybrid Sleep is not available when WSL2 is in use". Your "answer" is to turn off VMP, the *only* result of which is to turn off WSL2. I'm sorry, but I feel I should downvote since I don't believe this will ever be a helpful "answer" to anyone. If I'm wrong about this and you're right that this is a useful solution, then someone (maybe the OP) will upvote it at some point in the future and (more than) offset the downvote.